# Convert JQuery AJAX call to Angular 2 service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-services

I was using JQuery for http requests to .NET controllers (I'm using .NET MVC 4.5.2), but am now starting to use Angular 2, so I want to handle those JQuery AJAX calls with Angular 2 instead. Here is the JQuery I was using before, which worked just like I wanted:

```
$.get('/Plan/Variety/ListVarietiesInMenuForSelling')
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
```

How do I set up my Angular 2 service to accomplish the same thing? I've tried the code below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';  

@Injectable()
export class SellingMenuVarietiesService {
    private url = '/Plan/Variety/ListVarietiesInMenuForSelling';  // URL to web api    

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getVarieties() {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }       
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Instead, I get this error in the console:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined        core.umd.js:3462
```

The only examples I've been able to find handle JSON data and then use Angular to parse the data and format it into HTML. My controller already returns the HTML I need, so I don't need Angular to parse JSON. How do I get the http request to work like it did when I was using JQuery?

Just to be clear, for testing purposes I changed `return this.http.get(this.url);` to `return '<h1>test data</h1>';` and was able to get that to display correctly, so I know that the only issue is with the http request.

EDIT:
Here is the code where I call `getVarieties()`:

```
export class SellingMenuVarietiesComponent implements OnInit {   
    varietyListSelling: any;    

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private sellingMenuVarietiesService: SellingMenuVarietiesService) { }    

    ngOnInit(): void {        
        this.varietyListSelling = this.sellingMenuVarietiesService.getVarieties();
        console.log('initializing SellingMenuVarietiesComponent');
    }
}
```

And here is how I bind it to the HTML:

```
<div [innerHtml]="varietyListSelling"></div>
```

I used that instead of `{{varietyListSelling}}` because I need the string to be converted to HTML.

**UPDATE**

I upgraded TypeScript and removed my InMemoryWebApiModule and InMemoryDataService imports from app.module.ts, which is resulting in a new error. The error now says: `EXCEPTION: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4`

Is this because we are turning my HTML data into JSON? How can I just return the HTML like my JQuery was doing?

Comment: Can you add the code where you call the getVarieties() function?

Comment: I edited my post to include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class SellingMenuVarietiesService {
    private url = '/Plan/Variety/ListVarietiesInMenuForSelling';  // URL to web api    

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getVarieties(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.url).map(response=>{return response});
    }       
}
```

**then to consume the service:**

```
 this.sellingMenuVarietiesService.getVarieties().subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    });
```

**Update:**

The html you are trying to render is not rendering because the request has not completed when the template is being rendered. A possible solution for this is to add an ngIf to the div tag.

```
div *ngIf="varietyListSelling" [innerHtml]="varietyListSelling"></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I build that says: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: I changed res to (res:any) and that seems to have taken care of that, but now I have an error that says: Cannot find name 'Observable'

Comment: import it. I fixed it in the example.

Comment: The build errors are gone now, but I'm still getting this error in the browser console: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: because the request is async the request is being fired off and then the the template is rendered but the data hasnt come back yet. I suggest you add an ngIf to your div tag i.e. <div *ngIf="varietyListSelling" [innerHtml]="varietyListSelling"></div>

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm still getting that same error. ListVarietiesInMenuForSelling isn't popping up under my network requests in the dev console either.

Comment: The URL of the page I'm on is /Plan/Production and the request is to /Plan/Variety/ListVarietiesInMenuForSelling. Would this be considered a cross-domain request and would that be causing the problem?

Comment: no that shouldn't be a cross domain request. Can you put a log message inside the .subscribe when you are subscribing to service ?

Comment: Something like this?

ngOnInit(): void {        
        this.sellingMenuVarietiesService.getVarieties().subscribe(res => {
            console.log('subscribed to service');
            console.log(res);
            this.varietyListSelling = res;
        });        
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125453/discussion-between-eduardo-dennis-and-brett).

Comment: I updated my post with a new and more useful error that I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

You must subscribe to really send the request and read the response.

```
getVarieties() {
        return this.http.get(this.url).map((response: Response) => {
                return response.json();
            },(error) => {
                console.log(error);
                //your want to implement your own error handling here.
            });
    }
```

And your component would look like

```
    ngOnInit(): void {        
         this.sellingMenuVarietiesService.getVarieties().subscribe((res) => {
             this.varietyListSelling = res;
         });
        console.log('initializing SellingMenuVarietiesComponent');
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything to be able to use that code? I'm getting build errors. For example: "Cannot find name 'Response'" and "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Comment: Please see this for a complete get example http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/7343/crud-in-angular2-with-restful-api#t=201610111953558637191

Comment: I imported what I was missing and the build errors are gone now, but I'm still getting this error in the browser console: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Can you check network requests on dev console? to see if your request is sent and received properly.

Comment: It doesn't look like the request is even being sent. I'm not seeing it pop up under the network requests. Does this mean the URL i put in isn't right? If so, how would I change it? I copy and pasted the URL I was using with JQuery

Comment: Try sending request with full url (with http at front) like 'http://www.your.api.com/etc//Plan/Variety/ListVarietiesInMenuForSelling'

Comment: That didn't work either. The URL of the page I'm on is /Plan/Production and the request is to /Plan/Variety/ListVarietiesInMenuForSelling. Would this be considered a cross-domain request and would that be causing the problem?

Comment: No. That wouldn't be considered as cross domain request. Can you double check your component if you are using that subscribe function correctly? You should see a request even if url is wrong when you subscribe to it.

Comment: I updated my post with a new and more useful error that I'm getting.

Comment: remove .json() in the service and you should be fine. It's because your response it not json.

Comment: I removed the .json() and it returned an object, so I changed it to return response._body, which returned HTML like I want, however I got this warning in the dev console: "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)." Is that something I need to worry about? Do I need to change something?

Comment: response._body was giving me a build error, so I changed it to response["_body"] and that seems to have taken care of that problem. Still getting the warning.

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot find name 'Response'" and "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable' I have same issue but it's not a problem , It show error .map but it's work.